# Can you always make a bigger prime by rearranging the digits of a prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

So let's say we have 13, then we can make 31 from the digits but also for example 041 can make 401 which is also prime. And as extension is this true for any base we put the digits in?

Edit:I assumed that if I say 13 it is infinitely many 0's and then 13, so more like ..00013, so it is allowed to add 0's in front that you are not going to ignore.

Edit: Also not single digit numbers.

Comment: $2$ can only become $20$, $200$, etc., which are divisible by $10$, so not prime.

Comment: Your 31 is a counter-examle

Comment: @gammatester No, $3001$ is prime. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+3001

Comment: Where are the 0's in 31? Please refine your question.

Comment: @gammatester thanks I will change my question

Comment: @user236182 great find, I forgot to add a clause of my question.

Comment: @MyName: Even with the 'factor of the base' thing you run into issues, e.g. $3$ can only become $3 \times 10^n$ for some $n$, which is divisible by $3$. Likewise with $7$. Perhaps you just need to restrict to primes which have two or more digits. (I'm still not sure if it's true...)

Comment: @CliveNewstead Yes, I had to say it was also about multiple digits. Maybe I should remove and rethink and ask a water proof version. Sorry

Comment: @gammatester $103$ is also prime.

Comment: It is conjectured that $10^n+1$ is prime only for $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: Quite a difficult question, this one. At first I thought "Just use Dirichlet's theorem," but that does not actually solve it.